# What's the value of variable when setTimeout assigned to it?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to know what is the value of the variable when `setTimeout` get called and assigned to it. Unexpected value get logged, so being curious how this happening.

I tried to look some related question on stack and also look out on web but didn't get the exact answer.

**Update - I am seeking help to understand how the unique id which assigne d to variable get calculated ?**

```js
let a = setTimeout( () => {
  console.log('something will happen')
}, 2000)

let b = setTimeout( () => {
  console.log('something will happen')
}, 3000)

let c = setTimeout( () => {
  console.log('something will happen')
}, 4000)

console.log(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Please provide reason for the downvotes, it will help me improve for next time :).

Answer (score 2):

There is [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) on what type of values to expect.

Quote:

> The returned timeoutID is a positive integer value which identifies the timer created by the call to setTimeout(); this value can be passed to clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout.
>
> It may be helpful to be aware that setTimeout() and setInterval() share the same pool of IDs, and that clearTimeout() and clearInterval() can technically be used interchangeably. For clarity, however, you should try to always match them to avoid confusion when maintaining your code.
>
> It is guaranteed that a timeout ID will never be reused by a subsequent call to setTimeout() or setInterval() on the same object (a window or a worker). However, different objects use separate pools of IDs.

Comment: The returned timeoutID is a positive integer value which identifies the timer created by the call to setTimeout();  ---  `positive Integer` is just count of timer I had triggered

Comment: I  had read this before posting - I am just trying to understand whats the the `id` returned and how that get calculated ?

Comment: The id is just an opaque object that the JS object gives you, so you can refer to that timer in some way if you want to clear it again. You're not supposed to interpret the value in any way. It's just a value that the object generating it understands. It's just an id, like a database key is just an id. There's no semantics attached to it.

Comment: Ok fair enough - As I can conclude that it's the just numerical unique id get returned on each `setTimeout` call in global execution context

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable assumption. But the runtime can choose to generate these ids in any way it wants to, as long as it does not generate duplicates. So testing the return values is not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setTimeout` or `setInterval` the uniq id of particular timer is returned.

Usually it is just a number, incremented with every new timer and it is guaranteed that this number will never be reused.

You can use it only for cancelling timeouts or intervals with corresponding function `clearInterval` or `clearTimeout`.

More about returned value [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Return_value).

Comment: Hmm, I read it before posting and then thought to ask - Are we sure that it's incremented number of timer I had used ?

Comment: You should not rely on that number in any way. You should not predict id of the future timers. Use it only for cancelling particular timer.
Answer is "not always", because there can be other code except yours on the page. And that code probably creates other timers for its own purposes. 
So, for example, if you created a timer with id `3` it is not guaranteed that the next one you create will be `4`.

Comment: Fair enough - Thanks So we can conclude that it is just the one-by-one numerical `id` get returned to variable in single  global execution context

Comment: I have upvoted your answer as this get helpful to point what's happening - But would like to wait more and see if I get to know the actual internal process happening at the runtime. Thanks